# Emacs: disable Ido completion in Tramp mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp, ido

I often use ido for auto-completion and tramp to access remote server via ssh. My `.emacs` includes the following lines:

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
```

I want to disable Ido completion, when i'm browsing contents of remote server. Note that variable `ido-enable-tramp-completion` has nothing to do with my problem. Consider line `/root@site.com#1234:/var/www/file.txt`. I need Ido **not** to deduct the part after the colon (remote file path), i don't care about the part before the colon. I use ssh, and Ido makes Emacs lag for a few seconds every time i run `ido-find-file`, and when ssh timeout is over, Tramp tries to reconnect, asks me for a password and so on. This behavior is undesirable.

Emacs version - 24.0.94.1

**Edit (20.03.12)**: After contact with Ido author I tried to change the `ido-file-name-all-completions-1` to the following:

```
(defun ido-file-name-all-completions-1 (dir)
  (cond
   ((ido-nonreadable-directory-p dir) '())
   ;; do not check (ido-directory-too-big-p dir) here.
   ;; Caller must have done that if necessary.

   ((and ido-enable-tramp-completion
     (or (fboundp 'tramp-completion-mode-p)
         (require 'tramp nil t))
     (string-match "\\`/[^/]+[:@]\\'" dir))
    ;; TRAMP RELATED CODE DELETED
    nil)
   (t
    (file-name-all-completions "" dir))))
```

No success. I then changed regex to

```
"\\`/[^/]+[:@]"
```

and it worked - Ido was disabled, when minibuffer contained that match. However as Ido couldn't see files on a remote server, it started calling `ido-make-merged-file-list` to search for files in other directories every time i enter something. This made working with Ido on remote servers even more pain.

I also tried setting up variables `ido-slow-ftp-hosts` and `ido-slow-ftp-host-regexps` to `/root@site.com#1234`, didn't help.

Comment: This question seems related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397687/stop-tramp-from-opening-remote-directories-when-using-ido-mode).

Answer (score 12):

If you enter `C-x C-f` again you temporally disable ido-find and fall back to the default find-file.

For more information `C-h f ido-find-file RET`

To do this every time ido found a colon, I guess you have to write your own function for that.

Comment: If i do `ido-find-file` twice, then this error is thrown in `*Backtrace*` buffer - `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer")Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer")`. And where should i write this function?

Comment: You can't run ido-find-file twice. The `C-x C-f` command will not lunch the ido-find-file, it just fall back to find-file. Do not type `M-x ido-find-file RET` again. Type `C-x C-f`.

Comment: I see. Where should i write a function for ido seeing a colon?

Comment: For this case I don't think there is a hook. I suggest that you rewrote your own find-file method and copy most of the behavior of ido-find-file except when you see colon.

Comment: two years after and I find this post helpful!