# Stop tramp from opening remote directories when using ido-mode

Tags: emacs, tramp, ido-mode

I have a problem with ido-mode. As I cycle through work directories (using M-n), one of the directories is inevitably on a remote server, which makes tramp start authenticating.

I know I can edit the ido-work-directory-list-ignore-regexps variable, but maybe I'm misunderstanding that, or how it works with tramp. If the directory is someguy@example.com:/home/public/ what regexp should I use?

Comment: I asked an unanswered related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665235/emacs-disable-ido-completion-in-tramp-mode

Comment: (which has now been answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying this:

```el
(require 'ido)
(add-to-list 'ido-work-directory-list-ignore-regexps tramp-file-name-regexp)
```

Comment: It seems this works but I didn't realize it at the time because it had clashed with another solution I'd tried to use. I think I also had t use ido-wash-history after using this.